# Disabling buttons separately

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

as shown example

i want to

- if button1 is clicked then button2 get disabled
- if button3 is clicked then button4 get disabled

the reason why i use class and $this because i don't want buttons to conflict. otherwise i would use ID tag, so i want something if i have multiple buttons how can them be working without conflicting other like button1 and button3 are good working they don't conflict

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').on('click', '.btn-checkout', function(e) {
    $(this).html('proccesing order');
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $('.button2') = $(this).attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
  <div id="container">
    <h3>this area is alone</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn-checkout">button1</button>
    <button type="button" class='button2'>button2</button>

    <h3>this area is alone</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn-checkout">button3</button>
    <button type="button" class="button2">button4</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `$(this).next('.button2').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Seems like you want radio/option buttons? You're already using jQuery, maybe adapt this to your needs? https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/#radiogroup. Also, you're not telling us the complete set of behaviors. What if button 2 is clicked?  or button 4?

Comment: So did you delete your last question?

Comment: why `<div id="container">`  without `</div>` and not simply `<form method="POST" name="container">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.next()` to refer to the next element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').on('click', '.btn-checkout', function(e) {
    $(this).html('proccesing order');
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).next("button").attr("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
  <div id="container">
    <h3>this area is alone</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn-checkout">button1</button>
    <button type="button" class='button2'>button2</button>

    <h3>this area is alone</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn-checkout">button3</button>
    <button type="button" class="button2">button4</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

that ??

```js
const myForm = document.forms.container

myForm.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false) 

function myFunction(evt)  
  {
  // ignore other cases:
  if (!evt.target.matches('button.btn-checkout')) return 
  evt.target.nextElementSibling.disabled = true
  }

 // disable submit
myForm.onsubmit =evt=>evt.preventDefault()
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="container">

    <h3>this area is alone</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn-checkout">button1</button>
    <button type="button" class='button2'>button2</button>

    <h3>this area is alone</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn-checkout">button3</button>
    <button type="button" class="button2">button4</button>

</form>
```